# How to run one method till driver closed in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have one pop up which is displayed in 20 seconds after visiting the website and repeatedly displayed within 10 seconds if the user does not do any activity.
So I want to write a script that, whenever this pop up displayed closed the same and run the script.
How can I run this method or logic until the driver gets closed?

I want to closed following pop up:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFAhr.jpg

Comment: Your description is lacking key elements like: code examples, popup html or what have you tried so far. You might want to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

You may create Thread to invoke method for handling popup by using start() and this will keep on running till we call stop(). You may call your method from run().

```
Thread t1 = new Thread() {   
public void run() { 
    method1();  
}   
};  
t1.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple solution to handle random or unexpected pop up with listeners.

**Solution -1:**

Use `EventFiringWebDriver` which is a class to register listener events.

[Here](https://atechlearn.blogspot.com/2018/10/how-to-handle-unexpected-popup-alert-in.html?m=1) you can get a detailed example for implementation in well written blog

**Solution-2:**

Using `Java Dynamic Proxy` with proxy object by implementing `InvocationHandler` interface.

[Here](https://www.vinsguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-handle-annoying-random-popup-alerts/) you can find step by step process to implement it.